# Experienced Music Organization to Partner for Competition using Animal Sounds?

Tags: composition, acoustics

I am part of a scientific organization that uses animal sounds to study animals & their environments. In an effort to share our science with a wider audience, we were interested in hosting a US national 'Music Composition Competition', where artists would use some of our sounds in their composition. We would also make these sounds available for use (beyond the competition). From our geeky point of view, this could be both fun & educational. The competition would be open to all (students, amateurs, professionals), and all types of music. Our primary expectation would be the inclusion of some of our sounds. In a similar vein, there have been collaborations to create an [album using endangered bird sounds](https://www.npr.org/2020/07/16/891432319/a-new-album-turns-the-sound-of-endangered-birds-into-electronic-music).

We are looking for a partner organization that has experience hosting music competitions in the US and is trusted by musicians. What should we look for in a partner organization? And how can we determine if they are reputable?

Comment: Recommendations are generally off topic, so I'd suggest you may wish to modify your question to ask what to look for in a partner organization and how to determine if they're reputable. Also, which nation are you referring to? If you want a national competition, different countries and territories have different laws and regulations for contests.